# apt-mirror: can't create /media/ubunturepro/mirror directory at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 342 onto SMB-Share NAS

Tags: apt, repository, smb

I want to provide a repository for my LTS 16.04 Clients. They are i386 and amd64, the upgrade to LTS 18.04 is planned. When I started `apt-mirror` with 
`sudo apt-mirror` this error appears :

```
apt-mirror: can't create /media/ubunturepro/mirror directory at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 342 onto SMB-Share NAS
```

What I have done till now:

```
mkdir /media/ubunturepo/mirror
chown -R $User /media/ubunturepo/
```

Changed settings in the config `/etc/apt/apt-mirror`
Reinstalled apt-mirror

I have no suggestion what to do, anybody here please?

Here's the apt-mirror config:

```
#apt-mirror configuration file

############# config ##################
#
set base_path    /media/ubunturepro
#
set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
set skel_path    $base_path/skel
set var_path     $base_path/var
set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set limit_rate 250k
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############


deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a typo in your `etc/apt/mirror.list` file. The error message states that the directory `/media/ubunturepro/mirror` cannot be created, it appears you've made a directory named `/media/ubunturepo`. There is an extra `r` in the config file which doesn't appear in the `mkdir` command. Ensure both paths are the same and the error should vanish.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can accept the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left of this answer, which is the correct way to mark a question as closed.